# Dynamic Forms in symfony2 form.vars.value doesn't work

Tags: forms, symfony

In my VMachine form I have 2 fields (entities)  datastores and clusters, each cluster hosts many datastores. So I want to display dynamically the list of datastores according to the cluster choosen.

The entity datastore contain an id of the appropriate cluster which will allow me to apply filtration.

The problem is that I can't get the value of the current selected Item to filter my list of datastores:  here is my form view code:

```
<form action="{{ path('vm_create') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
{{ form_errors(form) }}
<div>
   {{ form_label(form.cluster) }}
   {{ form_errors(form.cluster) }}
   {{ form_widget(form.cluster) }}
</div>
<div>
{# the list of all datastores is passed on parameters to the form view from the   
 controller #}

{% block datastore_widget%}
{% spaceless %}
<select {{ block('widget_attributes') }}>
     {% for datastore in datastores %}    
            {{ form.vars.value.cluster }}
       {% if  datastore.cluster.id == form.vars.value.cluster  %}
            <option value="{{ datastore.nom }}">{{ datastore.nom }}</option>
       {% endif %}  
    {% endfor %}       
 </select>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock datastore_widget%}

</div>
```

It seems like the form.vars.value.cluster doesn't retrieve the current value of cluster selected!